# Count area of specific raster value inside polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics

I am currently working with annual forest loss raster data from Global forest watch.
(https://data.globalforestwatch.org/documents/14228e6347c44f5691572169e9e107ad/explore)

Data is built up so that forest loss for each specific year (2000-2019) is given a specific value from 0 to 19. 19 = 2019 forest loss, etc.

I also have a set of polygons representing hunting areas.

Is there any way to calculate the area of each specific raster value (year) for each of my polygons.

Ex. For HuntingArea1, 150 ha forest loss in 2019, 120 ha forest loss in 2018, 80 ha loss in 2017 etc.

Hope you get what I am looking for here.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Sorry. I work in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Zonal histogram
2. Multiply each output column/pixel count with the pixel size (can be found under layer properties) using Field Calcualtor or Refactor Fields

[image]